# Pass Nested Cloud Formation template, S3 bucket alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body file:////home//local//test//sampletemplate.json

Base on AWS Cloud Formation documentation, we can use Nested Cloud Formation. However, it only says call the Nested Cloud Formation template by uploading the template JSON file to S3 bucket.

Is there other way to pass the Nested Cloud Formation template? Something like: (I guess..)

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body file:////home//local//test//main-template.json file:////home//local//test//nested-template.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this feature is not available yet. Cloudformation resolves the nested dependencies at AWS side, e.g

```
"Properties" : {
          "TemplateURL" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/S3_Bucket.template"
```

If you give it a local file as TemplateURL, AWS will not be able to resolve this TemplateURL on server side.